# How can we update in more than 1 table?

Tags: sql, oracle

My database is Oracle 10g.

I have 5 different table and each one have column status which has default value 'N'.

Now I want to update in all 5 tables and make that status 'Y'.

So is there any single query or way so I can update in all 5 table, without making individual update query execution?

Comment: why not just alter each table to set the default to 'Y'

Comment: Do you mean update all the data, or change the default to 'Y' (or both)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if table names follow a regular expression you can write a PL\SQL code that:

- extracts all tables from table of oracle objects;
- constructs VARCHAR2 variable with dynamic statement to update value;
- use package DBMS_SQL to execute this dynamic statement;

bye

Answer (score 11):

Even if there is a complicated answer, I would prefer to just do:

```
UPDATE table1 SET columnX = "Y" ;
UPDATE table2 SET columnX = "Y" ;
UPDATE table3 SET columnX = "Y" ;
UPDATE table4 SET columnX = "Y" ;
UPDATE table5 SET columnX = "Y" ;
```

Now, if you have 5000 tables, lets talk about it.